# How many ideal ways are there to lay roads between cities?

Tags: geometry, optimization

Suppose you have n cities at the corners of a regular n-gon.  Your job is to make roads between the cities.   Each kilometre of road costs 1 dollar.  Suppose n(n-1) cars travel from each starting city to every other destination city along the shortest roads. Each car's use of gas costs x dollars per kilometre.

As we vary x, the ideal configuration of roads changes.  As x goes to infinity, the ideal configuration has n(n-1)/2 roads connecting all the cities.  For some x, there might only be n roads connecting the centroid to each city.  When x is zero, there are 5 roads.

For n=4, how many distinct graphs of ideal road networks exist?  What about for general n?

Comment: To be clear, your roads may only travel directly from one city to another in a straight bee-line path?  You mention a centroid there... [If you don't require this it can be more efficient](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dAyDi1aa40E).

Comment: @JMoravitz Cool, never seen this.  That's the idea *when x is zero*.  (You may only travel between cities along the roads.)